# Swift: Create stack of imageView with collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Hey i want to create stack of `UIImageView` like the photo, how to do this
It must be dynamic. How can I move the cells so that they are one below the other?

[image]

Comment: Check cover flow layout frameworks

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: I want the possibility that it scrollable, that I can enable scroll  with a boolean

Comment: Check this framework its looks good : https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` methods to make this kind of UI.

**Example:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.height, height: collectionView.bounds.height)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return -50
    }
}
```

In the above code

1. Configure `minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt` and `minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt` methods of `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`.
2. Since the cell in `collectionView` are aligned `left to right` default, so to get the desired result we need to align them `right to left`.

[image]

As shown in above screenshot, use `semantic` property of `collectionView` for `right to left` alignment of cells.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Edit-1:**

One way to centre the cells in `collectionView` is to play with `collectionView's` `width` and `centre it horizontally`.

**CollectionView constraints** - `top, width, centeredorizontally`

In `viewDidAppear`, manually calculate the `width` of `collectionView` according to the `numberOfItems`. In your case `numberOfItems = 3`

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let width = min((collectionView.bounds.height) * CGFloat((numberOfItems-1)/2 + 1), UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
    self.collectionViewWidthConstraint.constant = width
}
```

Comment: My collection has constraints leading, trailing. You too have set the constraints?

Comment: Cells are not by default centered in `collectionView`. You need to handle it either with autolayout or custom flow layout.

Comment: I have my 3 cells but they are right, I wanted it to be centered, how to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use UICollectionView Custom Layout .

> Collection view layouts are subclasses of the abstract UICollectionViewLayout class. They define the visual attributes of every item in your collection view. The individual attributes are instances of UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes and contain the properties of each item in your collection view, such as the item’s frame or transform.
>
> [The similar Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/392-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest)

This is a more complex layout , Change some parameters , you will get what you want.

[image: One]

Copyed from github , [mpospese/IntroducingCollectionViews](https://github.com/mpospese/IntroducingCollectionViews)

translate some to Swift

```
class SpiralLayout: UICollectionViewLayout{
    let itemSize: CGFloat = 170
    
    var pageSize: CGSize!
    var contentSize: CGSize!
    var radius: CGFloat!
    var cellCounts: [Int]!
    var pageRects: [CGRect]!
    
    var pageCount: Int!
    
    override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()
        pageSize = collectionView?.bounds.size
        let iPad = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad
        
        let scaleFactor: CGFloat = iPad ? 1 : 0.5
        let side = itemSize * scaleFactor
        radius = min(pageSize.width - side, pageSize.height - side * 1.2 )/2 - 5
        pageCount = collectionView?.numberOfSections
        var counts = [Int]()
        var rects = [CGRect]()
        for section in 0..<pageCount{
            counts.append((collectionView?.numberOfItems(inSection: section))!)
            rects.append(CGRect(origin:  CGPoint(x: CGFloat(section) * pageSize.width, y: 0), size: pageSize))
        }
        cellCounts = counts
        pageRects = rects
        contentSize = CGSize(width: pageSize.width * CGFloat(pageCount), height: pageSize.height)
        
    }
    
    
    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize{
        return contentSize
    }
    
    override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return !pageSize.equalTo(newBounds.size)
    }
    
    
    func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        var attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
        attributes.size = CGSize(width: itemSize, height: itemSize)
        
        //  ...
        
        return  attributes
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Question tag is swift